# Pass variable to make CFLAGS in shell script?

Tags: bash, shell, makefile, cflags

I'm trying to build some c programs with gnu make (4.1) through a shell script. I want to use different CFLAGS parameters, which I read from a file. The file contains lines like:

```
"-O1 -freorder-functions"
```

I am trying to do something like

```
while read line
do
    opts="$line"
    make CFLAGS="$opts"
done < $1
```

but all my attempts end up in the following error:

```
cc1: error: argument to ‘-O’ should be a non-negative integer, ‘g’, ‘s’ or ‘fast’
```

So I tried to change the file's contents to only the parameters after -O1 (-freorder-functions), and add the -O1 in the shell script:

```
opts=$(printf "\"-O%d %s\"", 1, "$line")
```

(and a lot of other things that seem less sensible) but I still get the same error message.

Hard-coding the parameter to make in the shell script works fine:

```
make CFLAGS="-O1 -freorder-functions"
```

Sorry if this is a stupid question, but I can't seem to find any examples of how something like this is done, and I'm new to shell scripting, so I don't really understand how it's treating the variables here. An echo of what I'm attempting to pass to CFLAGS looks okay to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With double quotes around the flags in the file and you dutifully quoting your shell variables properly, your `make` call ends up being

```
make CFLAGS="\"-O1 -freorder-functions\""
```

That is to say, with double quotes in the flags. This is passed all the way down to the compiler call, which means that the compiler call is something like

```
cc "-O1 -freorder-functions" -c foo.c
```

...which asks the compiler to use optimization level `1 -freorder-functions`, and it complains that that is not valid.

To solve this, I would remove the quotes from the file. You could also use `opts=$line` with `$line` unquoted, but that is not exactly safe.

Comment: Thanks, that gives me an idea of what might be happening.
However, in the second case I had removed the quotes from the file, hence the \" in printf. Without them - in something like $(printf "-O%d %s", 1, "$line") - it treats -O as an option to printf.

opts=$line unfortunately treats the "-freorder-fucntions" as "-f" and looks for a file called "reorder-functions".

Comment: Use `$(printf -- "-O%d %s" 1 "$line")`. By convention, option processing ceases after `--`. `printf` from the GNU coreutils follows this convention.